# Text disappearing in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code:

```
void Update ()
{
    TextDisplay();
    health -= 0.1;
}
void TextDisplay()
{
    healthText.text = "Health: " + health;
    comboText.text = "Combo: " + combo;
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
}
```

This code displays text on screen, and shows the values of the variables `health`, `combo` and `score`. `health` is a double, `combo` and `score` are both integers. Whilst `combo` and `score` show up perfectly, the text for `health` disappears when it has decreased by 1 (so since it starts from 100, when it reaches 99.0, it disappears).

Why could this be? I suspected it had something to do with `health` being a double (since the other two integer values worked fine). When I changed it to an integer (and -0.1 to -1) it started working.

The text, from Unity's editor, I have linked to each value hasn't been formatted outside of its colour and anchoring it to the top left corner.

An additional note, I have accessed these values in a different script belonging to a different game object. When the health is increased by 10 (due to the game object being "hit", upon which it cannot be "hit" again and is destroyed after) in that script, the health text shows up for an instant, and then disappears again.

Comment: It goes from saying "Health: 99.1 Combo: x Score: y" to saying "Combo: x Score: y" ? And there are no errors or exceptions printed in the log?

Comment: Yes that's right, and there no exceptions/errors in the log.

Comment: When it disappears, what does `healthText`'s object look like in the inspector?

Comment: The text continues to change in the editor (as the health value changes). It seems to gain quite a few decimal places after it goes below 99 (whilst going from 100 to 99, there's only 1 decimal place). Could that be the problem?

Comment: Can you check one thing? Does the object in the inspector have the "text" attribute still or it is blank? It sounds to me that you are experimenting a text size issue and the actual text is outside the render size.

Comment: Yes, the object still has the text attribute (and it updates as I'd expect it to as the health changes). The answer below fixed my issue though (seems like it was the decimal places that were the problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the decimal places increase to a point that the String overflows the size of the UI.Text box, which then clips it out of view.

To fix this, you can format the decimal before adding it to the string:

```
healthText.text = "Health: " + Math.Round(health,1); // one decimal place
```

Optionally, you may want to set the UI.Text vertical and horizontal overflow types to `overflow` and/or make the `rectTransform`'s size larger.